# How can i make my bot send back message when the Axiore Community say some random message? (v12)

Tags: discord.js

I was making a bot and i want it send message if the bot webhook Axiore Community send some random message, [This is Axiore Community webhook message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9taNt.png) and i want my bot send message back, how i can do that?? (Sometime that Axiore Community webhook send different message every 4 hours)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world!")
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Protect is already!")
})

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("is time to ping fruit stock!")
});

client.on("message", message => {
if (message.content === `Current stock`) {
message.channel.send("**New current stock!**")
}
})

client.login(process.env.token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if message author is webhook you can use:

```js
client.on("message" message => {
if(message.author.id == "id") { // change "id" to your webhook id
//your code
} 
})
```